# Bootstrap datepicker widget showing with no boxing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker in my project but something strange is happening as it is showing like this: [datepicker-problem-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxPkY.jpg)

In my code I am just doing this:

```
$('#mydatepicker').datetimepicker();
```

I am not having any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is working as intended .
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: No, it doesn't have the box around it

Comment: Can you provide your <div> block which has the id 'mydatepicker' ?

Answer (score 0):

This just work on bootstrap-datepicker 1.6.0 but not bootstrap 1.6.4
I don't know why my snippcode don't work but you can this is what you want:

```
jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/177/
```